# Applying Patches

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, patches, security-patch

In applying patches, If the provided zip file for the patch contains enterprise and open-source patches, should you apply both? or should you just apply the one same with your repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the notification from the Magento Side. Patches are very important for your site it increase your performance and secures your site. A Magento security patch is a software release. It provides the newest updates for Magento to fix security issues. The patch file helps in fixing major bugs.

Updates can prevent security issues and improve compatibility and program features. Software updates are necessary to keep computers, mobile devices, and tablets running smoothly -- and they may lower security vulnerabilities. Data breaches, hacks, cyber-attacks and identity theft have all been in the news

This is the link to Adobe Commerce from here you will get all patches and see how can we apply the patches.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/overview.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-patch.html

If you are using `open-source` then apply `open-source patch` or if you are using enterprise then apply `enterprise patch`.

If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: So can I assume that if my env is b2b/enterprise I should apply both patches (b2b.patch and enterprise.patch) if they are present on the zip file given?

Comment: Yes correct! You are right

Comment: please mark this an answer if this helps you, so I can help others

Answer (score 1):

The **patch** is a piece of the code that has some changes to fix the issues.
It's written according to the **Magento version**.

If you are using `open-source` then apply `open-source patch` or if you are using `enterprise` then apply `enterprise patch`.

Comment: So can I assume that if my env is b2b/enterprise I should apply both patches (b2b.patch and enterprise.patch) if they are present on the zip file given?

Comment: Apply only enterprise.patch